# Hide tabbar in React navigation dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My react native application has the following nested navigation structure

[image]

e.g. 
[image]

The one issue with this structure is that in the inner nested pages of stack (chat or task) I will need hide the bottom tabbar.
I can use this The https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabbarvisible to control the visiblity.

However, this cannot happen on load since the hiding is a dynamic activity for inner pages in the stack.

On connecting to redux, I can get the property in the tabbar component, but setting the tabbar visiblity then re-renders the component.

Is there any other approach for this common navigation pattern in android ?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it dynamically using **navigation.setOptions**

```
 const hideTabBar = () => {
   navigation.setOptions({
     tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' },
   });
 };
 const showTabBar = () => {
   navigation.setOptions({
     tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex' },
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (react-navigation v6) using useLayoutEffect and navigation.setOptions(). By using useLayoutEffect you ensure that tab bar is removed before the screen is painted so you won't see the tab bar initially and then see it disappear.  You can hide the tab bar via navigation.setOptions either in the Stack, or on the screen.  If you want to handle the hiding/showing of the tabbar on specific screens from the stack you first will need the route name.  Here is an example:

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator({ navigation, route });

export const ChatStack = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        switch (routeName) {
        case 'Chat':
            navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex' } });
            break;
        case 'ChatLanding':
            navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } });
            break;
        case 'ConvoThread':
            navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the tab bar in specific screens by rearranging the screen stacks like shown in official docs of version 5.x
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: this doc not at all clear and create more confusion for beginners. This doesn't solve the scenario like : TabNav( A -> Home, B -> Setting ), Stack (Home -> Latest, Popular). I want to display tab bar while a,B selection but hide it when i am inside latest,popular

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51692805/5895297 check this answer, maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using height, and it worked like charm.

```
style: {
     height: isFullScreen ? 0 : null
}
```

If you want to send this boolean from any specific screen, you can do it with setParams

```
 navigation.setParams({
     isFullScreen: true      // or false
 });
```

Then you can get this parameter with

```
const { isFullScreen } = route.params;
```

Answer (score -3):

in the screen that you want to hide the tabbar, use following code

```
static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarVisible: false,
}
```