# Hiding Bottom tabs in a certain screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I use a bottom tabs navigator imported from 'react-navigation-tabs'

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Homepage: {
    screen: Screen1
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2
  }
} , {
  initialRouteName:"Screen1"
});
```

Screen 1 is a stack navigator

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Homepage: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: Screen2
    }
} , {
    initialRouteName : "Homepage",
    headerMode:"none",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName === 'Screen2' ? false : true
    })
});
```

After some researches , I found the below solution , but not works

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName === 'Screen2' ? false : true
    })
```

It's a bad news because even to hide it from all screens , the below code also did not work

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarVisible: false
    })
```

the tabs always visible , after much researches and trying tens of solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Navigation how to hide tabbar from inside stack navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352081/react-navigation-how-to-hide-tabbar-from-inside-stack-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Screen1.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    let tabBarVisible = true;

    let routeName = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].routeName

    if ( routeName == 'ScreenX' ) {
        tabBarVisible = false
    }

    return {
        tabBarVisible,
    }
}
```

Comment: ljaz , it is hided , but Screen1 is a stack navigator hold many screens (ScreenX and ScreenZ) for example , I want to hide it from ScreenX in this stack navigator , you understand me ?

Comment: I have edited my answer, try that after creating your stack navigator.

Comment: ljaz , but the bottom tabs navigator is the parent , and the stack navigator is a child of it

Comment: Same , it still exist