# How to hide tabBar in specific Screen in React Navigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

How to hide tabbar in specific screen in `react-navigation 6` ... **Without changing navigation structure** as it's [the only option available in the docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes I used this approach

```js
    import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from ‘@react-navigation/native’;
   

     export const MainNavigator = () => {
      const getTabBarVisibility = (route) => {
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
        const hideOnScreens = [SCREENS.REVIEW_ORDER, SCREENS.ORDER_PAYMENT]; // put here name of screen where you want to hide tabBar
        return hideOnScreens.indexOf(routeName) <= -1;
      };
      return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name={SCREENS.ORDER}
            component={OrderNavigator}
            options={({ route }) => ({
              tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisibility(route),
            })}
          />
          <Tab.Screen name={SCREENS.REWARDS} component={SweetRewardsNavigator} />
          <Tab.Screen name={SCREENS.MY_ACCOUNT} component={MyAccountNavigator} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Would you have any idea how to do this when the tabBar is a custom component?

Comment: Hi @Aayush 
const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;
if (focusedOptions.tabBarVisible === false) {
  return null;
}


/// TabBar
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
      const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;

      if (focusedOptions.tabBarVisible === false) {
        return null;
      }

in component that need to hide

useEffect(()=>{navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible:false})},[])

Comment: This is what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098527/8602069

Answer (score 2):

That's how I made it.

I was looking for a way to hide the tabBar in all my screens on ProductsRoutes, except for the Home screen.(the initial route on the ProductsRoutes Navigator)

**Here's the ProductsNavigator:**

```
const ProductsRoutes = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
      <Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
      <Screen name="Catalog" component={Catalog} />
      <Screen name="Sales" component={Sales} />
      <Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

On my TabRoutes I'm using

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

to know which screen on ProductsNavigator is the Home screen and which one is not.
Based on that condition I can set display:'none' or 'display:'flex' to the tabBarStyle prop on Screen props:

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

const TabRoutes = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Screen
        name="Store"
        component={ProductsRoutes}
        options={({ route }) => {
          const focusedRouteName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
          if (focusedRouteName === 'Home') {
            return {
              tabBarStyle: { display: 'flex' },
            };
          }

          return {
            tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' },
          };
        }}
      />
    </Navigator>
  );
};
```

Hope this helps you in some way

Answer (score 1):

keyword is call `setOptions` and set `tabBarStyle` to `{display:'none'}`

at first, we set id on the parent navigator like

```js
 <Tab.Navigator
      id="tabs"
      tabBar={props => <FooterTabs {...props} style={{display: 'flex'}} />} //<-- add a style with display:flex means tabbar is visible by default
      >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

suppose we wanna hide the `tabbar` in `ChatScreen`

and in `ChatScreen`, key code like this

```js
const ChatScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent('tabs').setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
    return ()=>{
    //when leave this screen, and the hooks disposed, we set tabBarStyle to {}, means we will use the default style defined above, that is display:'flex'
 
      navigation.getParent('tabs').setOptions({tabBarStyle: {}});
    };
  }, [navigation]);
...
```

and you may noticed the `tabbar` in root tab navigator is a custom component, so inside `FooterTabs`, key code is like this

```js
const FooterTabs = props => {
  const {state, navigation, descriptors, insets, style} = props;
  const focusedRoute = state.routes[state.index];
  const focusedDescriptor = descriptors[focusedRoute.key];
  const focusedOptions = focusedDescriptor.options;

  const {
    tabBarShowLabel,
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard = false,
    tabBarVisibilityAnimationConfig,
    tabBarStyle, //<-- this is get from options,which we set from sub screens 
    tabBarBackground,
    tabBarActiveTintColor,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor,
    tabBarActiveBackgroundColor,
    tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor,
  } = focusedOptions;

  return (
    <HStack
      style={{...props.style, ...tabBarStyle}} //<-- we set the style over here, so when in some specific screen set tabbarstyle to override the display property to 'none', can final make tabbar hidden
      ...
```

this above code is get from [official bottom tabbar component](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/bottom-tabs/src/views/BottomTabBar.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple hook for this, works perfect, just call it on any screen `useHideBottomBar();` to hide the bottom bar on that screen. Change the styles to match your design.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import ThemeContext from '../../contexts/ThemeContext';
import useColours from '../useColours';
import {useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import {themeFontFamily} from '../../helpers/theme';

export function useHideBottomBar() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const {darkMode} = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  const colours = useColours();
  const theme = useTheme();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
      tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
      tabBarBadgeStyle: {display: 'none'},
    });
    return () =>
      navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: darkMode
            ? theme.colors.surface
            : colours.secondary050,
          borderTopColor: darkMode
            ? theme.colors.surfaceVariant
            : colours.secondary200,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          height: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 110 : 80,
          display: 'flex',
        },
        tabBarBadgeStyle: {
          ...themeFontFamily.OpenSansSemiBold,
          backgroundColor: colours.errorDark,
          color: colours.white,
          fontSize: 11,
          padding: 0,
          marginTop: 6,
          display: 'flex',
        },
      });
  }, [navigation]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll = 0; // at top

const onScroll = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    let contentOffsetY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    let diff = contentOffsetY - scroll;
    if (diff < 0) {
      navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex'}});
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'}});
    }
    scroll = contentOffsetY;
  };
```

pass this to onScroll of any scrollview component

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a stack navigator screen in which to hide parent and grandparent navigators' tabBars and headers.

```
export const MyNav = ({
  route,
  navigation
}) => {

   React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);


        if (routeName === 'RouteThatNeedsHiddenTabBarsAndHiddenHeader') {
          navigation.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } });
          navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({ headerShown: false });
          navigation.getParent()?.getParent()?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' } });
        } else {
          navigation.setOptions({
            tabBarStyle: { ...defaultTabBarStyle, display: 'flex' }
          });
          navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({ headerShown: true });
          navigation.getParent()?.getParent()?.setOptions({ tabBarStyle: {display: 'flex' });
        }
      }, [navigation, route]);

      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="NormalRoute"
            component={NormalScreen}
          />
          
          <Stack.Screen
            name="RouteThatNeedsHiddenTabBarAndHiddenHeader"
            component={SpecialScreen}              />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
  }
```

A simpler way if only 1 screen needs to be adjusted would be to run the code in target screen as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70153935/1979861

Answer (score 0):

For me `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` returned `undefined`. So I had to implement some other solution.
I created navigation named state in redux in which I added property `tabBarHidden`. Then in tab navigation screen I did this.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MainNavigator = () => {
  const tabBarHidden = useSelector(state => state.navigation.tabBarHidden); <-- redux selector

  return <Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => (
     <View style={{
         display: tabBarHidden ? 'none' : 'flex'
      }}>
       <BottomTabBar {...props} />       <-- imported from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
     </View>
  )}>
    // your tabs
  </Tab.Navigator>
}
```

Then you can use redux actions to update the property
For example if you want to hide tab bar in chat component you have to do something like

```
 useFocusEffect( <-- imported from @react-navigation/native
    useCallback(() => {
     dispatch(hideTabBar()) <-- redux action to set tabBarHidden to true

     return () => {
       dispatch(unhideTabBar())
     }
   }, [dispatch]),
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solve for this state from React Native Docs and it's work for me:
Just change your navigation structure.

Example:
**With this structure, when we navigate to the Profile or Settings screen, the tab bar will still stay visible over those screens.**

```
function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

---

But if we want to **show** the tab bar only on the Home, Feed and Notifications screens, but not on the Profile and Settings screens, we'll need to change the navigation structure. The easiest way to achieve this is to nest the tab navigator inside the first screen of the stack instead of nesting stack inside tab navigator: this is the solve.

```
function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```