# Possible to hide tab navigator from screen in stack nested in tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I have a Stack Navigator with some screens and an initial route like "Profile", and when I navigate to "Options" via a `navigation.navigate("Options")` from the "Profile" screen, I don't want to see the bottom tabs. Here's an example of what I have:

****ProfileNav.js****

```
export default function ProfileNav () {
   return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Profile">
         <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}>
         <Stack.Screen name="Options" component={OptionsScreen}>
      </Stack.Navigator>
   );
};
```

****TabNav.js****

```
export default function TabNav () {
   return (
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}>
         <Tab.Screen name="ProfileNav" component={ProfileNav}>
      </Tab.Navigator>
   );
};
```

I'm using React Navigation v6. I've seen the [Hiding tab bar in specific screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) docs describe how to swap around screens to achieve hiding the tabs from a single screen, but in this case I'm trying to have the parent screen of the `ProfileNav` stack still show the bottom tabs, but I don't want the rest of the screens in the stack to show them, which is not what the docs help in achieving unless I missed something.

So how do I achieve hiding the bottom tabs from select screens of a stack navigator nested in a tab navigator?

I have also tried passing in `tabBarVisible` into the "Options" screen options, but this didn't work.

Comment: check my solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73689855/3190833 works fine to me

Comment: check my solution explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73689855/3190833 works fine to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass the `navigationContainerRef` to the `NavigationContainer` and get the current route name via `getCurrentRoute` in the `TabNav` component in order to hide the tab bar for specific screens that are handled by a different navigator.

Then, pass the route name as a state to the Tab navigator and decide for which screens to show the tab bar and for which not.

In this case, you want to show the `TabBar` for the route `Profile` only. Here is a minimal working example.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from "@react-navigation/native"

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

function ProfileNav () {
   return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Profile">
         <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
         <Stack.Screen name="Options" component={OptionsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
   );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNav (props) {
  const hide = props.routeName != "Profile"
   return (
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         <Tab.Screen name="ProfileNav" component={ProfileNav} options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarStyle: { display: hide ? "none" : "flex" }
        }} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
   );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return <View></View>
}

function ProfileScreen(props) {
  return <View>
     <Button title="Nav to options" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Options")}></Button>
  </View>
}

function OptionsScreen() {
  return <View></View>
}

const ref = createNavigationContainerRef();

export default function App() {
  const [routeName, setRouteName] = useState();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={ref}
      onReady={() => {
        setRouteName(ref.getCurrentRoute().name)
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeName;
        const currentRouteName = ref.getCurrentRoute().name;
        setRouteName(currentRouteName);
      }}
    >
       <TabNav routeName={routeName} />
     </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And here is a working [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/navigation-hide-tab).

Comment: Your answer works, my app is a bit more complicated than the example but I'll try out this concept

Comment: It should work nevertheless. Let me know if it doesn't and provide me with more details of your application, then I am sure we can fix open problems.

Comment: I was able to implement your logic except I was getting some weird behavior with props.routeName I'm assuming bc of prop drilling (my nav tree is large). I decided to create a context which returns the routeName, so where you have setRouteName in NavigationContainer I have handleRoute, which is imported from my context. Works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Your code and the snack code are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the react navigation implementation just keep outside whichever stack screen that should not be part of bottom navigation as a stack screen in app component like below.

```
export default function ProfileNav () {
return (
  <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Profile">
     <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}>
  </Stack.Navigator>
   );
};

function HomeTabs() {
   return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="ProfileNav" component={ProfileNav} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
 }

 function App() {
    return (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Options" component={OptionsScreen}>
       </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
    );
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call TabNavigator stack from StackNavigator instead, that should works.

```
export default function TabNav () {
   return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}>
         <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}>
      </Tab.Navigator>
   );
};

return(<NavigationContainer
>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNav} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Options" component={OptionsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>

 </NavigationContainer>)
```

Comment: Can't navigate to Options from Profile with this

Comment: @patataskr Edited the answer. I tested that and I was able to navigate from profile to options. Make sure that you properly set your NavigationContainer and Stack. If TabNav called from Stack `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNav} />` then you should be able to navigate to Options from Profile.

Answer (score -1):

you can use react's useLayoutEffect with getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute function from @react-navigation/native

first, we need to extract navigation and route from tab navigator params

then using useLayoutEffect every time the focused layout is changed we are checking for focused route name
if the focused route name matches our route name ( in your case "Options" ) where are going to set "tabBarVisible" to "false"

```
export default function ProfileNav ({ navigation, route }) {
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
        if (routeName == "Options") {
        navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false });
        } else {
        navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: true });
        }
    }, [navigation, route]);
   return (
      <Stack.Navigator initialRoutName="Profile">
         <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}>
         <Stack.Screen name="Options" component={OptionsScreen}>
      </Stack.Navigator>
   );
};
```

Comment: Still seeing tab bar on OptionsScreen