# How to remove TabNavigatorBar from specific screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I try to remove tab navigator, however my screen is in createstacknavigor and createstacknavigor is in tabnavigator.

Like this:

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  registration: createStackNavigator({
    Splash: SplashScreen,
    Regis: Registration,
 
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    MainPath: createStackNavigator({
      Main: MainPage,
      Web: WebPage,
    }),
  }),
});
```

I go from Main to Web. But in "Web" screen MainPath tab navigator visible if I move "web" outside of createStackNavigator and put it in createBottomTabNavigator then I can remove with:

```
 tabBarVisible: false
```

However I need to go back from Web to Main because I want to see Main screen as I left. I didn't it change anything.

I hope I was able to explain what I want.

Comment: Not getting your question

Comment: your tabNavigator should be the child of stackNavigtor, rather than stack NAvigtor being child, if you don;t need tabs in stack screens.

Comment: i will put another screens  to mainFlow to make tab screens. i didnt do yet

Comment: Which version of react-navigation do you use? 4.x?

Comment: @vahdet 4.4.3 i use

Comment: Even your question (especially the part below the code snippet) needs clarification, I hazard a  _guess_ that this can be something close to what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51352081/4636715

Comment: simply, i want to hide tabnavigationbar in "Web" screen. i just want to do this