# Can a View cover the bottom tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, z-index

I am in a situation within my project where it would be convenient to "prohibit the user from interacting with the app". I would like to do this, by rendering an invisible screen that is covering the entire display.

I notice that once the bottom tab is rendered, I cannot seem to force a view over it. Is there a way I can give my view priority over everything? I have tried zIndex but no luck, I just want my view to cover the entire screen.

I have an example demo [here on snack expo](https://snack.expo.dev/EII48dnwsx) where you can replicate my issue exactly. I have also included some code below that gives you the gist.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
      <Tab.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```
export default function ScreenA() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Screen A. 
      </Text>
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'pink', height: 500}}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Is it possible to make this view cover the entire screen? Including the bottom tab and top?</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: A quick, dirty, and easy solution would  be to just render a blank modal that you remove whenever you want the interactions to be available. I think you may have to configure to the modal to not be canceled on presses outside of it boundaries

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean by this. How could I ensure the modal would cover the bottom tab? Do you mind editing my snack expo post to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352081/react-navigation-how-to-hide-tabbar-from-inside-stack-navigation/64789273#64789273) I've come up with a solution that hides/show the tab bar buttons base on the state of a variable:

```js
const [showTabBar, setShowTabBar] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarStyle: { display: showTabBar ? 'flex' : 'none' },
    });
  }, [showTabBar, props.navigation]);
```

A [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/jMHr48M35)

While it removes the tab  bar entirely, it does ensure that the tab bar is non-interactable. If you find it necessary to have the tab bars visible, but unpressable, you could first create a custom tab bar component, add some variable that will make the buttons do nothing when active, use it in `Tab.Navigator` and then render it at the bottom of the screen in `ScreenA` when `showTabBar` is false (make sure to set the unpressable variable to true)

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/8kc1Apvb8

Comment: This approach disable tab bar presses, but the tab bar is still visible. It also requires a bit more effort to get TabBar icons

Comment: It also will disable tab bar button presses on all screens so  if you use it make sure to you set tabBarIsActive back to true

Comment: Thank you for these Phantom, I am going to give the post a tad longer and if nothing else, ill accept yours as the answer. I am curious what you mean by rendering a blank modal, your quick dirty fix that is.

Comment: To be honest the modal idea may not be as dirty as I thought. It doesnt require creating a custom tab navigator, or adding extra props to screens https://snack.expo.dev/yJrp4XxdW

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/7DuhiVcyY

Comment: Wait thats perfect. Thank you!