# React Native Navigation Structure To Hide Tabbar in certain pages

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I currently have the following structure for my app:

(Stack)

- Launch (Stack)
- App (Tabs)

  - Home (Stack)
  - Discussions (Stack)
  - …

Inside the discussion stack I have a screen (Chat) where I'd like to remove the tabbar. From what I understood in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens), if I want to have this behaviour I should place the Chat screen at the top like this:

(Stack)

- Launch (Stack)
- Chat (Screen)
- App (Tabs)

  - Home (Stack)
  - Discussions (Stack)
  - …

Is this the correct approach? I saw there where also ways to hide the tabBar inside a specific stack as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789273/15275654) but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct approach. Moreover, you don't have to place the ChatScreen on "top" of the TabNavigator, it only need to be placed outside the TabNavigator.

Just follow the docs and be confident, docs instruction is always the best approach of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, but you can also open the chat as modal screen.